# Python - Modifying beginning and end of list in one iteration vs modifying one end at a time using two iterations speed

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm

While looking at the discussion for [Product of Array Except Self](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/submissions/) I came to try two different techniques and I can not wrap my head around this. Why does modifying a list at the beginning and end using one iteration (Solution 1) slower than modifying a list from the beginning and then in reverse using two for loops (Solution 2)?

Where my confusion comes in:

- Initializing the list to all 1's is O(n) from my understanding (this is the same in both algos so it shouldn't make a difference)
- Setting/getting an item in a list is O(n)
- Looping through a list is O(n) each time

Therefore Solution 1 should be :

- O(n) for init list
- O(n) for the iteration
- a few O(1)s for getting/setting elements in the list
- = O(n + n) = O(n)

Solution 2 would then be:

- O(n) for init list
- O(n) for the first iteration
- O(n) for the second iteration
- a few O(1)s for getting/setting elements in the list
- = O(n + n + n) = O(n)

So they are both technically O(n), but Solution 2 still has a second iteration and yet somehow it runs FASTER! Not the same, FASTER!

I also know that Leetcode isn't the best at judging runtime speed since it varies greatly, but i have run this so many times and it always shows Solution 2 running faster. I don't understand what I'm missing here.

Solution 1

```py
ans = [1] * len(nums)
        
left = 1
right = 1
        
for i in range(len(nums)):
   ans[i] *= left
   ans[-1-i] *= right
   left *= nums[i]
   right *= nums[-1-i]
        
return ans
```

Solution 2

```py
prod = 1
ans = [1]*len(nums)
for x in range(0,len(nums)):
    ans[x] *= prod
    prod *= nums[x]
            
prod = 1
        
for x in range(len(nums)-1, -1 , -1):
    ans[x] *= prod
    prod *= nums[x]

return ans
```

Comment: So you're asking why `-1-i` is slower than `x`?

Comment: Is that what is causing the run time discrepancy? Isn't `-1-i` constant because it's just asking to count which index to access in reverse. So the retrieval would still be O(1). Right?

Comment: It's a *bigger* constant. It's an operation. That takes some time. More than *no* operation.

Comment: I guess I'm just shocked at the fact that any constant, no matter how complex, is more complex than doing two iterations when compared to one.

Comment: I don't see how that's shocking. Your single loop's body does more work than the two bodies of the two loops combined.

Comment: @stackiee, It's not looking up the element at index `-1-i` that takes more time, it's computing `-1-i` that takes the extra time.

Comment: I understand, and really appreciate, both comments. I guess it's just I always looked at O(1) being preferable to an O(n) operations but I guess that is not always the case. Would it be preferable to have a counter initiated to `len(nums)` and then decrementing that value by one after each iteration in the for loop?

Comment: @stackiee, it's important to understand that big-Oh notation describes asymptotic behavior, i.e. what happens as input gets large, not an absolute measure of run time. Take a look at the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm for more discussion on this sort of thing.

Generally in Python, your best bet for iteration is to use simple loops, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, or the tools provided by `itertools` for more complex iterations. If you find yourself being https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_clever_by_half, keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Is* it faster?

It's not necessarily faster. You didn't specify how you got your results. I tested it in CPython and PyPy and while solution 2 wins in CPython, solution 1 wins in PyPy. (See below for the test code.)

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.6
$ python test.py
Solution 1 time: 2.9916164000001118
Solution 2 time: 2.6632864999996855
$ python test.py
Solution 1 time: 2.857291400000122
Solution 2 time: 2.854712400000153
$ python test.py
Solution 1 time: 2.7937206999999944
Solution 2 time: 2.5544856999999865
```

```
$ pypy3 --version
Python 3.6.12 (7.3.3+dfsg-3~ppa1~ubuntu18.04, Feb 25 2021, 20:14:47)
$ pypy3 test.py
Solution 1 time: 0.07995370000026014
Solution 2 time: 0.09105890000000727
$ pypy3 test.py
Solution 1 time: 0.07695659999990312
Solution 2 time: 0.08727580000004309
$ pypy3 test.py
Solution 1 time: 0.07859189999999217
Solution 2 time: 0.09762659999978496
```

## Why might solution 2 be faster in CPython?

Well, notice also that CPython is *vastly* slower than PyPy. Regular CPython is interpreted. Interpreting Python code is very, very slow compared to running compiled code. The Python interpreter loops, executing bytecode operations. Every opcode in the loop must be interpreted every time. However, the infrastructure of the for loop itself, that is, the code that invokes the iterator and checks if it should continue looping, and in particular the `range` iterator *itself* are not executing any interpreted Python code at all. They are all pre-compiled native code. They have negligible cost compared to the execution of your Python code instructions inside the loop. And solution 1 does *more work* inside the loop. Not a lot more, but it has to do two extra subtractions every time.

In contrast, in PyPy, you can expect that everything gets compiled to native code. This makes your Python code in the body of the loop much faster. So much faster that it's now comparable in cost to the code implementing the `range` iterator. At this point the fact that you're not applying the iterator twice *does* become a big enough deal to let solution 1 win out.

## A word of caution

All that said, I might be wrong! It's really hard to know for sure how code will perform, and I've not done the exhaustive dissection required to be certain here - I've just come up with a plausible explanation. It's also possible that one algorithm is less cache-friendly than the other, or pipelines better in the CPU. I just don't think that kind of thing is likely to make much difference in interpreted CPython.

I *did* find that if you change solution 1 to remove the subtractions, it runs in about the same time as solution 2 in CPython. Of course, it gets the wrong answer, but that does tend to make me thing that my explanation is a reasonable one.

## An aside on time complexity

You linked to a Leetcode problem statement which constrains the input so that it is guaranteed that every prefix and every suffix of `nums` has a product that fits in a 32-bit integer. (I assume they are signed integers.) This is very constraining on the size and values in `nums`. Unless there are `0`s in `nums` (which make the problem trivial) then `nums` can't have more than about 31 values that aren't `1` or `-1`. This is why I picked a test array with 20 integers in the range [1..7]. However, this is *very small* to be talking about asymptotic complexity. Asymptotic complexity tells you something about how an algorithm behaves when N becomes "large enough" that you can ignore the constant time factors. If N has a small upper limit you might never reach "large enough".

Even where algorithmic complexity *is* a useful tool, it still can't tell you which of two O(N) algorithms will be faster. All it can tell you is that if two algorithms have *different* time complexity, then there is *some* N above which the algorithm with lower complexity will consistently be faster.

## Test code

```
import timeit
import random

def s1(nums):
    ans = [1] * len(nums)

    left = 1
    right = 1

    for i in range(len(nums)):
       ans[i] *= left
       ans[-1-i] *= right
       left *= nums[i]
       right *= nums[-1-i]

    return ans

def s2(nums):
    prod = 1
    ans = [1]*len(nums)
    for x in range(0,len(nums)):
        ans[x] *= prod
        prod *= nums[x]

    prod = 1

    for x in range(len(nums)-1, -1 , -1):
        ans[x] *= prod
        prod *= nums[x]

    return ans

def main():
    r = random.Random(12345)
    nums = [r.randint(1,7) for i in range(20)]
    print('Solution 1 time:', timeit.timeit(lambda:s1(nums),number=500000))
    print('Solution 2 time:', timeit.timeit(lambda:s2(nums),number=500000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```